# IONIC 2 Image upload to php server

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm getting an error when i pick a photo from the gallery its showing the alert as "server error". Please help me with my problem >_< I'm using Image Picker and cordova file transfer

```
upload(){
ImagePicker.getPictures({
maximumImagesCount: 1,
           width: 127,
         height: 127,
         quality: 75
}).then((results) => {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

 var url = "http://ifund.esy.es/register.php"
            var targetPath = results[i];
            // File name only
            var filename = targetPath.split("/").pop();
            const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
            var options = {
                fileKey: "file",
                fileName: filename,
                chunkedMode: false,
                mimeType: "image/jpg",
                params: {'directory': 'upload', 'fileName': filename, 'username': this.username, 'password': this.password, 'first_name': this.fname, 'last_name': this.lname, 'email': this.email, 'address': this.address, 'contact': this.contact, 'bday': this.bday}
            };


    fileTransfer.upload(url, targetPath, options).then((results) => {
      alert('file uploaded successfully  ' + results);
    }, error => {
          alert('server error');
     });
    }

 }, (err) => {
  let alert = this.alert.create({
    title:'Warning',
    subTitle: "ERROR",
    buttons: ['OK']
    })
  alert.present(); });
```